# Is the Ricci tensor controlled by the metric?

Tags: linear-algebra, geometry, differential-geometry, inequality, riemannian-geometry

Does an estimate of the form
$$Cg(X,X)\leq \operatorname{Ric}(X,X)\leq \frac{1}{C}g(X,X)$$
hold for all $X$ under appropriate assumptions? Thanks.

Comment: Positive Ricci curvature...

Comment: If, for example, you assume that the manifold is compact, the Ricci curvature is positive definite, and allow the constant $C$ to depend on $g$ and the Ricci curvature, then the answer is obviously yes. If you want $C$ to be independent of the metric, then the answer is no. You might want to consider a simple analogous question: Does an estimate of the form $Cf(x) \le f''(x) \le C^{-1}f(x)$ for any smooth function $f$ on the domain $[0,1]$?

Comment: The body of your Question should have a reasonably self-contained problem statement.  In particular you should identify what kind of thing $X$ is (and what kind of thing $C$ is) before asking if something "hold[s] for all $X$", and limit what considerations inform "under appropriate assumptions" to avoid the trivial response that it holds whenever $X$ satisfies one of the parameterized inequalities.

Answer (score 1):

Your estimate would imply, that Ric$(X,X)\geq 0$. This isn’t always the case. However, the statement that $C_1 g(X,X) \leq Ric(X,X)\leq C_2 g(X,X,)$ for some (maybe negative) constants $C_1,C_2$ is true on any compact manifold.

Comment: But the constants depend on $g$ itself.